# What currency does the term "flip sense verb" have in linguistics?

Tags: syntax, terminology, verbs

In [a recent comment on the question *Ergative Verbs and some discussion about them*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/ergative-verbs-and-some-discussion-about-them/8607#comment20583_8600), [jlawler](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/482/jlawler) introduced a term I had not previously encountered:

> *The rose smells good* is completely different; this *smell* is a [**flip sense verb**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), with quite different syntax.

The term I've put in bold links to [an answer to a question on our English Language sister site, *“Taste” is to “flavor” as “touch” and “sight” are to what?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/105101/revisions) Where [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) uses the term a few more times:

> ...
>   Two of the verb classes differ in whether they're volitional, and the other one is an experiential sense with special **"Flip"** syntax.
>   ...
>   The third type is the **Flip verbs**: sound, look, smell, taste, feel.
>   Again the three chemical/kinesthetic senses don't change, though only feel works as a **Flip verb**:
>   ...
>   The subject of a **Flip verb** is not the experiencer, but rather whatever is causing the sensation being experienced.
>   ..

So I'm wondering if this is a term I ought to be familiar with. Some brief Googling hasn't turned up very much. Is it perhaps better known under another name, or only used by a single author? What is the provenance of this term? Where can I learn more about the concept named by this term?

---

<sup>I just noticed that of course *jlawler* and *John Lawler* must be the same person. I wonder how to get different usernames on two SE sister sites (-:</sup>

Comment: I've not encountered the term before. I have encountered the claim that such verbs are copula, though, although I disagree. I think such verbs indeed form a special class, and if there are established sources that call them "flip verbs", I might want to adopt the term into my usage.

Comment: Also known as "[psych predicates](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=psych+predicate)". They have perceiver/experiencer subjects, and either DOs or PPs expressing the source of the perception/experience. Frequently emotional, often adjectival, some formed from old past participles.

Comment: Correction. That's the description of emotional flip/psych predicates, like _fear, afraid/scared/suspicious (of),  amazed/surprised/aghast (at),_ etc. The flip sense verbs have subjects that refer to the stimulus and a complement that describes the effect; the perceiver is expressed optionally in a _to_ clause -- if not expressed, the perceiver is understood to be the speaker. I.e, _That looks/sounds/feels/smells/tastes funny (to me)_. These are called "flip" because they appear to invert the position of the arguments in _I heard/saw/tasted/smelled/felt that_.